# Crop cirlcle image and merge with a marker with transparent bg

Tags: php, png, gd, alpha-transparency, php-gd

Im trying to crop a square image and merge it with a Marker, but i cant get the copped circle image to be transparent.

When is save the circle image as a PNG , it shows it OK with Transparent corners, but when i open it in Photoshop it has a White Color on the corners like the final image below.

[image: This i s the original picture im using]

[image: I get this one ,but i want it without the white corners]

here is the code im using:

```
//SAVED THE CIRCLE PNG IMAGE
            $width = 320;
            $height = 320;
            $img1 = '';
            switch($fileExt){
                case '.png':
                    $img1 = ImageCreateFrompng($img= $image_config['new_image']);
                break;
                case '.jpg':
                    $img1 = ImageCreateFromjpeg($img= $image_config['new_image']);
                break;
                case '.gif':
                    $img1 = ImageCreateFromgif($img= $image_config['new_image']);
                break;
            }
            $x=$width ;
            $y=$height;
            $img2 = imagecreatetruecolor($x, $y);
            $bg = imagecolorallocate($img2, 255, 255, 255); 
            imagefill($img2, 0, 0, $bg);
            $e = imagecolorallocate($img2, 0, 0, 0);
            $r = $x <= $y ? $x : $y;
            imagefilledellipse ($img2, ($x/2), ($y/2), $r, $r, $e); 
            imagecolortransparent($img2, $e);
            imagecopymerge($img1, $img2, 0, 0, 0, 0, $x, $y, 100);
            imagecolortransparent($img1, $bg);
            header("Content-type: image/png"); 
            imagepng($img1, './img/deviceImg/pin'.$datetime.'.png');
            imagedestroy($img2); // kill mask first
            imagedestroy($img1); // kill canvas last

            //MERGING IT WITH THE PIN
            $width = 320;
            $height = 320;
            $image_1 = imagecreatefrompng('./img/deviceImg/pin.png');
            imagesavealpha($image_1, true);
            imagealphablending($image_1, true);
            $image_2 = imagecreatefrompng('./img/deviceImg/pin'.$datetime.'.png');
            imagesavealpha($image_2, true);
            imagealphablending($image_2, true);

            imagecopy($image_1, $image_2, 40, 22, 0, 0, $width, $height);
            imagepng($image_1, './img/deviceImg/pinASD'.$datetime.'.png');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transparency is only copied with [imagecopymerge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php), not [imagecopy()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php).  So your penultimate line:

```
imagecopy($image_1, $image_2, 40, 22, 0, 0, $width, $height);
```

Should be changed to:

```
imagecopymerge($image_1, $image_2, 40, 22, 0, 0, $width, $height, 100);
```

Note the extra parameter (`pct`) at the end.  As per the manual:

> The two images will be merged according to pct which can range from 0 to 100. When pct = 0, no action is taken, when 100 this function behaves identically to imagecopy() for pallete images, except for ignoring alpha components, while it implements alpha transparency for true colour images.

Comment: You are totally right, i tryed this case another day but didnt work for some reason , but now works perfectly thanks a lot